# When can I play on Furbottom's Features in Battleblock Theater?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, battleblock-theater

I started playing Battleblock Theater this weekend and there is a multiplayer mode known as Furbottom's Features which has some special achievements for unlocking achievements and prisoner heads. I tried playing it and I got a "mode is not available at this time message". Is this mode only available on certain times of the day or will it be implemented in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If this was in the past the answer would be "will it be implemented in the future"**

The Furbottom's Features was released a couple of weeks after the game released (around 19 April), you can play it now.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem the asker is having.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it means that at the time of the question the mode was unavailable because it was to be implemented in the future, and right now is already implemented

Comment: Ah. Putting that info in your answers would be helpful. Not every voter is going to check the dates on questions.

Comment: i've edited so there is no misunderstandings